# Checkout commit, keep changes in working dir

Tags: git, working-directory

My working directory is dirty, and that's how I like it.

I would like to checkout a certain commit, but `git` complains:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
```

Fair enough. How can I tell `git`:

> Please do not overwrite them. Keep the changed files as they are, and
>   checkout the rest from the selected commit.

Comment: Would `git stash` `git checkout commit` `git stash apply` work for you?

Comment: Recovering from stash has exactly the same problems.

Comment: @XavierGuihot Better said, unstashing tries to merge, and gives me (*gasp*) merge conflicts, which is definitely *not* what I want. I want to keep my changed files **exactly** as they are, no messing around with them please.

Comment: Never tried this, but maybe this would help https://questionfocus.com/force-git-stash-to-overwrite-added-files.html

Comment: instead of checking out the commit, you could check out all files from that commit that are not changed in your working directory

Comment: @LinFelix one by one? And git can not do that for me?

Comment: You could use the merge-strategy option `ours` (https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies#merge-strategies-ours) if you merge the commit instead of checkout (and after commiting your changes). It will keep the files you modified as they are in your working directory. Would this apply to your case?

Answer (score 1):

> My working directory is dirty, and that's how I like it.

Okay then! :-)

> How can I tell git: *Please do not overwrite them. Keep the changed files as they are, and checkout the rest from the selected commit.*

You can't—at least, not directly.

It's not clear *why* you want to do this, and that might affect *how* you should go about doing this as well.

Note that one thing you *can* do is extract any particular commit to a new work-tree (if your Git is new enough: 2.5 is the minimum, 2.6+ is better) using `git worktree add`.  If your Git is older you can simply clone your repository to a new clone and use that to extract the commit into the new clone's work-tree.

You can also use `git archive` to package up any particular commit as a tar or zip archive.  Once you have that archive, you can do whatever you like with it.

Both of these alternatives have the side effect of *not* altering your existing work-tree's `HEAD` and index in any way, along with, of course, not altering any of your work-tree files.  (Or, it might be better to say that `git checkout` has the side effect of altering `HEAD` and the index, except that those are not really *side* effects; those are *primary* effects, since `HEAD` denotes the current commit, and the index indexes the work-tree, and `git checkout`'s purpose is to switch commits, updating the work-tree).

One last option is to go ahead and make a commit, which of course violates the "how I like it" part of your setup.  But you can make this commit on a temporary branch, or even on no branch at all—the latter is what `git stash` does, though it actually makes two or three commits depending on the arguments you give.  Once you have a commit, you can use all the commit-based tools to work with that commit, such as cherry-picking.

Comment: I face this problem while I was refactoring code. After I made some changes, some tests failed. In this case, I would like to roll back to the previous commit without losing my current progress.

Comment: @user11452194: the thing to keep in mind is that your work-tree is *yours*, to do with as you will. Only the `.git` is Git's. You can move all your work-tree files to somewhere else, or mess with them all you like, as long as you don't touch the `.git` contents. When you ask Git to do things like `git switch` or `git restore` or `git reset --hard` you're telling Git: *overwrite my work-tree*, and it will do that at that time, as you asked it to, so *at that time* you must be sure you're OK with Git overwriting your work-tree contents.

Comment: The two separate commands `git switch` (which checks before clobbering unsaved work-tree work) and `git restore` (which just overwrites your work-tree) are both spelled `git checkout` in Git versions predating Git 2.23, so be careful which kind of `git checkout` you do if you use the old `git checkout` command: are you using the safe one, that says "would clobber file" and doesn't clobber the file, or the forceful "clobber my files right now!" form? It's clearer when you're using the Git 2.23-and-later two-separate-commands.

Comment: In general, there are two ways to save work-tree files: (1) Copy them somewhere outside of your Git repository. Now they're totally unrelated to your repository, and won't be affected by anything you do *with* the repository. Or (2) Commit them. Now they're in a commit; every commit is frozen for all time. Use the commit's hash ID, and Git commands, to get them back later.